# Correct conceptual level to consider when deciding between dependency, association, aggregation, and composition?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

To be very clear: I am **NOT** asking the difference between those four types of association. I know there are plenty of questions already asked about that. Unfortunately, for each of those questions there are a dozen plausible but different answers because each answer is based on thinking about the system on a different conceptual level.

In other words: Some descriptions (both in textbooks, on SO, and the internet at large) about these concepts speak only in terms of high-level conceptual view of a system. They say things like, "Because a room could not exist without the building, then the building is 'composed' of rooms."

On the other hand, others speak only in terms of the actual run-time existence of the objects in memory. Saying things like, "If the Room object will be deleted when the Building object is deleted, then Building is 'composed' of Room." (Before anyone jumps in, there is a distinction between the two. If another object holds a reference to that Room object (or your destructor is just not thorough enough in C++), then that Room object could still exist in memory.) Those same, run-time-oriented, explainers will also say things like, "If ClassA 'holds' a reference to ClassB, but ClassB could still exist without ClassA, then ClassB is 'aggregated into' ClassA." Technically, this is just the other side of the "Room object / Building object" coin because that Room object could possibly exist in memory independently of that Building object regardless of one's conceptual notion of how rooms **should** behave in the real world.

There are even people who say it is impossible for Java to have any composition at all because all Room objects that are "composed into" a Building object are really just references so they exist on the heap, outside the memory space for that "composing" Room object, even though that Room object may be doomed for garbage collection as soon as the Building object is deleted. If one is going to get that picayune about things, I could say that a real room can exist without a real building because it is possible to tear a real building down, leaving just that one room standing.

So, as you can see, whether that Building object is a composition or an aggregation of those Room objects entirely depends upon your particular implementation, and a single error in coding could switch it from one to another. Something tells me that UML is not meant to go to that level of detail and specificity. That is what code is for.

So, my question goes to the fundamental purpose of UML: When creating UML diagrams, am I supposed to be only thinking at the higher conceptual level of rooms and buildings in general? Or am I supposed to be thinking about how I plan to implement this specific code?

My question is also **not** about your **opinion** about what **should** be the correct conceptual level to consider. I want to know if there is an accepted industry standard for this. If there is no accepted industry standard, just say so. If the industry standard is just that people decide for themselves what level they are considering, just say so. If there is no industry standard about whether there even is an industry standard, then just state that as well.

I am well aware that answers to this question could easily devolve into opinions. Please try to avoid that. I want to know if there are existing specifications (or truly authoritative authors) that specify one way or another.

Answer (score 3):

Actually the use of UML does not imply to have a distinct level of abstraction. UML will work for almost all abstraction levels. What people did is to build a process called [Model Driven Architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-driven_architecture) (and lots of similar/more complex ones). There you deal with different abstraction levels. And indeed the semantic of a composition would be different in the 3 abstraction layers. While in the lower lever you would (/could) use it with your room/building interpretation while on the concrete layer(s) you would interpret it for memory handling. In any case, there should be a (meta) model documentation explaining the use of composition.

Comment: So.. Because UML does not specify an "abstraction level," I am free to choose whichever seems appropriate for this particular diagram. And, best practices would suggest that I stay consistent within a diagram and document that abstraction level in the diagram. Correct?

Comment: I'd say that's the way to go.

Comment: @GeertBellekens You're probably right, though the standard does not leave space for discussions. I'll remove it.